# Purity of perverse cohomology sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, perverse-sheaves

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a morphism of projective varieties over a finite field. Let $K$ be a perverse pure sheaf on $X$.

**Are the perverse cohomology sheaves of $f_*(K)$ pure?**

I am just learning the subject and may be ignorant of something basic.

Answer (score 6):

By Deligne's theorem, the complex $f_*(K)$ is pure.

The fact that a pure complex has pure perverse cohomology sheaves follows from Theorem 5.4.5 of [Faisceaux Pervers by Beilinson, Bernstein, Deligne](https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Faisceaux%20pervers.pdf) which says that the perverse cohomology sheaves of a pure complex are summands of the complex (plus the straightforward fact that summands of a pure complex are pure)

I'm pretty sure that the statement you proved is implicitly proved along the way to the proof of Theorem 5.4.5, but I didn't find such a statement explicitly in my quick scan of BBD.

Comment: Thank you. There is a little point which I do not quite understand. In Thm 5.4.5 perverse cohomology is a direct summand of a pure complex not over the original finite field but over its algebraic closure. Does it matter?

Comment: You can use Hard Lefschetz to see that the decomposition is defined over the finite field. See Deligne's article https://publications.ias.edu/node/414